# leaflet geojson point layer coloring

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, maps, geojson

i have a geojson link with to many points data and i want to coloring some points using values from  `field_1`.

i use this code but dont work dont coloring this point and keep default color style.

any idea where i have wrong ?

```
    var data= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("url/path/",{
        style:function colors(feature) {
            switch (feature.properties.field_1){
                case 'some value':
                    return{
                        color:'#20ff78',
                        fillOpacity:0.8
                    };
                    break;
            }
        },
       onEachFeature:function (feature,layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('some text');
    }
    });
    data.addTo(map);
```

UPDATE

json example :

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[15.94, 30.63]]}, "properties": {"f1": 2, "f2": "value", "f3": "other value"}}]}]
```

Comment: Please add enough code to be considered a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including one or two GeoJSON features that get (or don't get) styled as expected.

Comment: @IvanSanchez i update my question and i add GeoJSON features